# JQuery - Calling Function to a Div with the same class name

Tags: jquery

I want to use the same class for div's as they serve the same purpose, although I cannot find a way to get it to work without outputing the same result to both of the div's.

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function divide(a, b) {
        $(this).text(a + " / " + b);
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <body>
 <div class="division" ><script type="text/javascript">divide(3,7)</script>
 </div>
 <div class="division" ><script type="text/javascript">divide(12,75)</script>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to work at all: http://jsfiddle.net/mZbp7/ What do you think happens when you put the JavaScript statement into the `div`?

Comment: That's what I need help with, I thought if once it was called, JQuery's $(this). , would replace it with the text.

Comment: You are just calling a function, how should jQuery or JavaScript know which element it relates to? When calling a function this way, `this` will refer to the global object, which is `window`, it does not refer to any DOM element. Maybe you have to provide a better example, I don't see why you just don't write `3/7` and `12/75` in each `div`.

Comment: I can't just write it because I need to call those two parameters from a server.

Answer (score 3):

**simple**

http://jsbin.com/ubodeg/edit#javascript,html,live

and if you want the actual result :

http://jsbin.com/ubodeg/2/edit

Comment: You don't need `parseInt` as the values are already integers. You should also include the code here imo.

Answer (score 1):

In your example just write this

function divide(a, b) {
        return (a + " / " + b);
    }

Comment: I did this, but nothing seemed to happen?

Comment: How should this work? The returned value is not magically set as content of the `div`s.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `divide` function to return the string result instead of trying to use jQuery `.text()`

You could also update your divs to include IDs. Then inside your function, you could do:

```
$('#'+$(this).attr('id')).text(a + " / " + b);
```

That second way is far from idea however.

Answer (score -1):

give each div a different ID and pass that into your divide() method.  Use the ID to differentiate between divs

Comment: Although I need to use classes.

Comment: As far as I know you can add a class and an ID to any element

Comment: if we put id to every element then why do we need to use classes ? :)